# Explicitly declaring service gateway in Java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I have an application using Spring Integration where I have multiple handlers (strategies) for some service gateway methods, and I want the deployment launcher to be able to select which specific handlers are loaded. Since component scanning will pick up all of the handlers indiscriminately, I prefer to explicitly declare JavaConfig `@Bean`s for them.

This works fine for the service objects themselves, but I can't find a way to load the service interface itself in Java without `@IntegrationComponentScan`. My current workaround is to include a "one-liner" XML file with an `<int-gateway>` tag and `@ImportResource` it, but I'd really prefer a more direct solution.

Is there any straightforward way in JavaConfig to tell Spring Integration to create a proxy service interface for a specific class?

Answer (score 2):

`GatewayProxyFactoryBean` is for you. 
This class is used to populate bean definition from `<int:gateway>` tag and from `MessagingGateway` annotation.

So, you can do like this:

```
@Bean
public GatewayProxyFactoryBean myGateway() {
     GatewayProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new GatewayProxyFactoryBean(YourServiceInterface.class);
     factoryBean.setDefaultRequestChannel(gatewayRequestChannel());
     return factoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Am I correct that the default channel is unnecessary if I've explicitly set channels on the relevant methods? If so, could I simply `return new GatewayProxyFactoryBean(MyGateway.class)`?

Comment: Yes. It should be enough.